# Certificate Revocation check failing in Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, windows-server-2016, ocsp, certificate-revocation, certutil

Command

certuil.exe -verify

fails with the error - 'Cannot find object or property. 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND)' in Windows server 2016. The error is not seen in 2012 \ 2008.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any relevant certutil output?

Comment: CertUtil: -verify command FAILED: 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND)
CertUtil: Cannot find object or property.

Comment: Also getting the error:  Failed "OCSP" Time: 0
    Error retrieving URL: Internal server error (500). 0x801901f4 (-2145844748 HTTP_E_STATUS_SERVER_ERROR)